# NHibernate SaveOrUpdate without primary key

Tags: nhibernate, orm, entity, composite-key

## The Situation

I've got a database table that is mapped via NHibernate (3.3.3-SP1). The application is running on .NET4.0 and the mapping is done via FluentNHibernate (1.4.0).

```sql
CREATE TABLE Movies
(id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 yearPublished DATETIME NOT NULL,
 name NVARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
 description NTEXT NOT NULL)
```

The data would be something like this:

```
id | yearPublished | name                   | description
---+---------------+------------------------+--------------------------------------------
1  | 1968          | 2001: A Space Oddyssey | An epic drama of adventure and exploration
```

## The Problem

I'm creating new entities of this table and want to avoid adding more than one entity for the same real world thing. I know that there is `Session.SaveOrUpdate` and that there is also a way to make it work with composite and natural ids but that's not really what I want since my entities actually have a primary key and I really only need the composite key for making sure that no duplicates are in the DB.

```cs
var movie = new Movies
{
    yearPublished = 1968,
    name = "2001: A Space Oddyssey",
    description = "An awesome journey to Jupiter"
};

// Behavior right now:

// Adds a new movie besides the fact that
// the movie is already in the database
// but now has two entries
session.SaveOrUpdate(movie);

Assert.IsTrue(movie.id == 2 && movie.description == "An awesome journey to Jupiter");

// What I really want is to be able to define what
// makes an object unique other than the primary key;
// in this scenario it should look for a combination
// of "yearPublished" and "name"
session.MyAwesomeSaveOrUpdate(movie);

Assert.IsTrue(movie.id == 1 && movie.description == "An epic drama of adventure and exploration");
```

Is this functionality in place in NHibernate (e.g. through a custom mapping) or do I have fetch the candidates from the DB and do it by hand?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by adding a unique constraint on the natural key fields in the database and using an exception converter to convert the SQL Server exception into one my application can handle.

```
public class SqlServerExceptionConverter : ISQLExceptionConverter
{
    public Exception Convert(AdoExceptionContextInfo adoExceptionContextInfo)
    {
        var sqlException = adoExceptionContextInfo.SqlException as SqlException;
        if (sqlException != null)
        {
            // 2601 is unique key, 2627 is unique index; same thing: 
            // http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/26/sql-server-difference-between-unique-index-vs-unique-constraint/
            if (sqlException.Number == 2601 || sqlException.Number == 2627)
            {
                // my custom exception
                return new UniqueKeyException(sqlException.Message, sqlException);
            }
        }
        return adoExceptionContextInfo.SqlException;
    }
}
```

Another approach I can think of is to query the database for a matching record before the insert but that's not foolproof because a record could be inserted between the select and your insert.

Comment: I'm not really a fan of using exceptions for control flow but at least it seems to work. Although, I've been using the DIY method in the end

Comment: There's no other option if you want to handle database exceptions. You can try to avoid them by pre-checking data or including a where clause but catching the exception and converting it to something your application can handle is the only foolproof method.